# Capybara 302 redirect got empty page

Tags: ruby, testing, capybara

I am writing a test using Capybara 3.11.0. I am visiting the page with redirect and I want to check the page for content after redirection. Capybara by default follows a redirect, but I got an empty result.

```
page.driver.post("basket/add/?params=")
page.driver.status_code.should eql 302
page.should have_css(".item-form")
```

The last line fails that content is not found. If I try to print the content, before status code check I got

```
page.driver.status_code
=> 302

print page.html
=> nil
page.body.size
=> 0
```

But there is a site redirected from controller with the result.

Please, how can I get the content?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The `post` method doesn’t follow redirects, so there is no content to check.  Additionally  using any `page.driver.xxxx` method is usually an indicator that you’re doing something you shouldn’t be doing with Capybara. Capybara is designed to be used in feature/system tests which replicate a users behavior. Users don’t care about specific status codes they only care about what’s shown on the page so you should just be using the normal `page.xxx` methods to visit a page, interact with it and check content.  If you really want to test `POST`S to URLs and verify status codes you should be writing request tests (which don’t use Capybara)